# popup modal opens in full sreen in javascript

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, partial-views, bootstrap-modal

I have a table from which i am trying on row button click to open a modal containing the details of the object with the rowId. when my button is pressed i go into code behind and do a query that searches the data from the database, then in javascript i send the data to the modal and open it. The table is placed inside a partial view on it's own so that i can pass here a model. the problem that i am facing is that the modal is not opening as a modal but it is opening as a partial view inside the page.

here is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btn').click(function () {    

        debugger;
        var url = $('#rowDetails').data('url');
        $('#rowDetailsBody').html(data);            
        $('#rowDetails').modal('toggle');
        $('#rowDetails').modal('show');           
    });
});
```

row detail is the name of my modal that is contained in a partial view, and rowDetailBody is the Modal-Body.

this the function that i do to get data:

```
 public ActionResult ShowDialog(int id )
    {
        PSEntities _context = new PSEntities(true);
        var data = //some query here

        return PartialView("ShowDialog", data);
    }
```

i return to a partial view named showDialog the data that is fetched from the database.

and this is my patialView:

```
 <div class="modal fade" draggable="true" id="rowDetails" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3 id="myModalLabel">SMS @item.SmsMT.Id</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="rowDetailsBody"> 

            <table style="width:100%;" class="table table table-hover table-striped  table-condensed export-table" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">

                        <label>@ViewRes.SharedStrings.SmsID</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SmsMT.Id)
                    </td>
                </tr>                    
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-sm" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>

        </div>
    </div>
```

plz can someone help me and tell how to open the window in a modal instead of full screen

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have missed modal-dialog and modal-content wrapper from your modal markup.

```
<div class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: I added the missing tags and it didn't change anything. the modal is still opening in full page in place of the initial page.

Comment: Can you post your rendered HTML output? a fiddle would be nice.

Comment: table is eliminated from the view, and the only thing that is present is the modal with the table data. basically the functions run in a gd way but i think that when i do "return partialView("ShowDialog"),data); in the ShowDialog function i am eliminating the data from the page and only rendering the the partial view